# How to run monte carlo similation in python within spacified upper and lower range of values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, simulation, montecarlo

I am trying to run Monte Carlo simulation for 520 weeks and 10000 trials. I am using the below code for the purpose.

my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import norm


u=log_return.mean()
var=log_return.var()
drift=u-(0.5*var)

stdev=log_return.std()
weeks=520
trials=10000
z=norm.ppf(np.random.rand(weeks,trials))
weekly_returns=np.exp(drift+stdev * z)

price_paths=np.zeros_like(weekly_returns)
price_paths[0]=data2.iloc[-1]
for t in range(1,weeks):
    price_paths[t]=(price_paths[t-1]*weekly_returns[t])
```

What I want to do is to set upper cut (bound) and lower cut (bound) so that the simulated values remain within these range.

for example: if a series is to have lower bound as 10 and upper as 100, it means, the entire series values will lie within 10 and 100 (both inclusive).

Can it be done?

Comment: It won't be efficient but you could reject the samples that violate your bounds. That is, just do a `if (sample not within bounds): continue`. You could also look into truncated probability functions; https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html

Comment: Thanks @NaphatAmundsen, I already have done that but in this case i will get varying numbers of results.. and, trancation do not give me smooth plots. I just want to run simulation between the bounds.

Comment: If you have limits and truncation is not allowed, then you don't have a normal distribution.  Maybe check if the data you are trying to replicate isn't following some other distribution (perhaps some form of beta distribution)